# Using this temperature function, make a table of data spanning 30 years

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

So basically I defined a temperature function:

```
temps[y_]:=Map[(makeOrdinal[#,y])&,WeatherData["KGRB","MeanTemperature",
{{y,1,1},{y,12,31}, "Day"}]
```

that will give the average temperatures for KGRB (Green Bay) for any given year as long as it is in this format.

```
temps2010=temps[2010]
```

My problem is that I do not know how to create the code that will show the temperatures from 1983 to 2012. Then map the parameter finding function

```
params=FindFit[temps2009, -a*Cos[2*Pi*(t - b)/365] + c, {a, b, c},  t]
```

across this table to construct a table of parameter values for the 30 years in question, therefore it will not be 2009 as shown in the code.

Comment: Hint: What would you get if you used Map[ temps, something ]? What should "something" be? That doesn't quite give you the result in exactly the right form so what could you do to to get it into the form you need for the next step?

Comment: `Table[FindFit...`. must say id be a bit surprised if that fit works very reliably, but that a different question. in any case mathematica.stackexchange.com is a better place